# Proper setup for sync'ing a large data sets (System to System) using Observables using RxJS

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I am trying to sync data from one system to another using a NodeJS Application to help track the sync process transactionally. Below is a modified snippet of what I am trying to accomplish. The interval time and tap is just for logging and testing purposes. So far it is doing what I am trying to do but doesn't feel right or seem correct.

The overall diagram of what I am trying to do: 
 1. Note: The far left items are kick starter actions (UI/End User Action & an internal interval to call getActiveCourses)

*Edit: My main question is, how do I use RxJS Observables to create a queue management-state-like object allowing for the individual items to self-sync and self-dispose once completed.

*Edit 2: I am not asking for help on designing an entire system but in how properly setup an Observable that can manage a course listing, then have another Observable monitor it to filter out specific courses. On those filtered courses, each course should be an observable of its own to sync data pertaining to itself then self unsubscribe.

1. **Should the main getActiveCourses be a BehaviorSubject or a Subject?**
   Keeping current value or only push upon retrieving the latest group
   of courses.
2. **Should the processCourses be a Subject?** I my thought was that this would be a capture of the latest subscriptions to the filteredCourses and process them like a queue. I am having a hard time detecting if this is true.
3. **Lastly, do I need to create a third Observable to truly capture and isolate the actual courses to be synced?**

It was pointed out to me that having a tap and subscribe instead of subscription is not a reliable way of performing this task. A suggestion was to use concatMap() but I am finding that to be still linear and I would rather to have the data be more organic in flow as some data may need more updates than others.

Please note that most of the application is done and the only thing I am really trying to do is efficiently write the code.

[image]

```
const courseProcessQueue = new BehaviorSubject({});
const processQueuedCourses = new Subject();

processQueuedCourses
.subscribe((data: any) => // problematic area!!!!!!
  data.pipe(
    filter((d: any) => d.length <= 2),
    tap(loadCourseEnrollments),// end of problematic area
  )
  .subscribe(d => console.log('[processQueuedCourses]', d))
);
processQueuedCourses.next(courseProcessQueue);

interval(500)
.pipe(
  map(loadActiveCourses),
  flatMap(data => data),
  map(courseSyncQueue),
)
.subscribe(() => console.log('pushed new course queue state'));

courseProcessQueue.subscribe((courses: any) => 
    console.log('[courseProcessQueue]', courses.length)
);

function loadActiveCourses() {
  let limit = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1)
  return from(getActiveCourses('externalId id', limit));
}

function courseSyncQueue(courses: any) {
  courseProcessQueue.next(courses);
}

async function loadCourseEnrollments(courses: any) {
  console.log('PROCESSING ENROLLMENTS!!!!!!!!')
  courses.map(course => console.log('PROCESSED:', course.externalId));
}
```

Output:

```
[getActiveCourses()]
PROCESSING ENROLLMENTS!!!!!!!!
PROCESSED: Course-001
PROCESSED: Course-002
[ processQueuedCourses] [ { id: '1',
    externalId: 'Course-001' },
  { id: '2',
    externalId: 'Course-002' } ]
[courseProcessQueue] 2
pushed new course queue state
[getActiveCourses()]
[courseProcessQueue] 8
pushed new course queue state
[courseProcessQueue] 9
pushed new course queue state
```

Comment: think you need to scale down your questions a bit.

Comment: I would love to help with RxJS but you ask to design an entire system... can you narrow down your question to just the processing pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after researching flatten strategies, I was able to create a working solution to the problem I was facing. The overall problem was that I was subscribing to an observable within a observable. This was basically a mergeMap strategy as was not was I was going for. Turns out I needed to do a switchMap strategy along with using the scan operator to check the incoming data against the current/accumulated data.

This is the article that really helped me understand what was going on: [A Super Ninja Trick To Learn RxJS’s “switchMap”, “mergeMap”, “concatMap” and “exhaustMap”, FOREVER!](https://medium.com/@shairez/a-super-ninja-trick-to-learn-rxjss-switchmap-mergemap-concatmap-and-exhaustmap-forever-88e178a75f1b)

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as bluebird from 'bluebird';
import { interval, from, BehaviorSubject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { mongooseConfig } from './config';
import { getActiveCourses, getCourseById } from './logic/data-service';
import { Course } from './models/course';
// import { inspect } from 'util';

(<any>mongoose).Promise = bluebird;

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
  mongoose.connection.on('error', (err: any) => { console.log(err); });
});

mongoose.connect(mongooseConfig.database, mongooseConfig.options);
/**
 * Test for updates to a course
 */
Course.findOneAndUpdate(
  {id: '_69107_1'},
  {'availability.available': 'N'},
  {upsert: true}
)
.select('-_id id externalId updatedAt')
.exec()
.then(console.log);
Course.findOneAndUpdate(
  {id: '_69107_1'},
  {'availability.available': 'Y'},
  {upsert: true}
)
.select('-_id id externalId updatedAt')
.exec()
.then(console.log);

/**
 * END TEST
 */


/**
 * getActiveCoursesFromDB => from() => switchMap() => BehaviorSubject()
 */

// just use 3 seconds for now, update to 15 * (60 * 1000) later
const refresh15MinutesAgo = 3000;
const filteredCourses = new BehaviorSubject([]);

// get the active courses that are stale test
interval(1000).pipe(
  map(() => from(getActiveCourses({select: '-_id id externalId updatedAt', limit: 3}))), 
  switchMap(courses => courses),
  map(courses => courses.filter(course => course.updatedAt < Date.now() - refresh15MinutesAgo))
).subscribe(setFilteredCourses);

filteredCourses.pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    // ensure there is a current obj
    if (curr) {
      // if the current obj is not an array then check it directly
      if (!Array.isArray(curr)) {
        if (!containsObject(curr, acc)) {
          return [...new Set([...acc, curr])];
        }
      } else {
        // otherwise process only the ones that are not in the current stack
        return [...new Set([...acc, ...curr.filter(c => !containsObject(c, acc))])];
      }
    }

    // either first iteration or curr was undefined
    return acc;
  })
).subscribe(logOut);

//test to inject a course and update, simulating a front end override call
timer(6000).pipe(
  map(() => from(getCourseById('4', {select: '-_id id externalId updatedAt'}))),
  switchMap(c => c)
).subscribe(setFilteredCourses);

// helper function to push data into the BehaviorSubject
function setFilteredCourses(data) {
  filteredCourses.next(data);
}

function logOut(output: any) {
  console.log('[logOut]', output);
}

// helper function to test if an object is in our list
function containsObject(obj, list) {
  const ids = list.filter(c => c.id === obj.id);
  if (ids.length > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Output:

```
//creating an update for test
{ id: '3',
  externalId: 'Course-003',
  updatedAt: 2018-09-11T02:00:39.986Z }
{ id: '3',
  externalId: 'Course-003',
  updatedAt: 2018-09-11T02:01:31.710Z }

//time passes
[getActiveCourses()]
[logOut] [ { id: '1',
    externalId: 'Course-001',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-07T16:45:58.295Z },
  { id: '2',
    externalId: 'Course-002',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-07T16:45:58.295Z } ]
[logOut] [ { id: '1',
    externalId: 'Course-001',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-07T16:45:58.295Z },
  { id: '2',
    externalId: 'Course-002',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-07T16:45:58.295Z },
  { id: '3',
    externalId: 'Course-003',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-11T02:01:31.710Z } ]

//more time passes, 4 was injected into the stack/queue
[getActiveCourses()]
[logOut] [ { id: '1',
    externalId: 'Course-001',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-07T16:45:58.295Z },
  { id: '2',
    externalId: 'Course-002',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-07T16:45:58.295Z },
  { id: '3',
    externalId: 'Course-003',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-11T02:01:31.710Z },
  { id: '4',
    externalId: 'Course-004',
    updatedAt: 2018-09-07T16:45:58.295Z } ]
```